# Disable Username Change Email Notification for Org Migration/Consolidation

Tags: migration

We are in the middle of a Salesforce org consolidation. In this project we are going to keep the users' usernames the same from org to org.

To do this, we are data loading the users in the new org and configuring the user specific items. These will be data loaded using appended user names, i.e. future_first.last@email.com.

When we are ready to perform the cut over we will data load appended usernames in the outgoing org, i.e. old_first.last@email.com. This will free up the username in Salesforce realm to be created, by upsetting against the previously created users, in our destination org.

The problem this poses is when we data load the appended usernames in the former org users will receive an email informing them of the new username. The username does not become permanent, or available to be recreated in the destination org, until the user clicks the link in the email and logs in, thus accepting the change.

We have validated the entire process works. We need a method to prevent users from receiving the change username notification and a method to make the data loaded new usernames in the original org permanent without the user accepting/approving the change.

We have thousands of users and cannot perform this manually if we point all their emails to a few project team members. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deactivate the users and update users with updated usernames.

This will not make email verification for users to verify the username change.